# Matlab : Opposite function of "primes" in matlab

Tags: matlab, primes

Is there any opposite function of "primes" in matlab?

(Primes : Prime numbers less than or equal to input value)

What if i want to find greater than or equal to input value?

Thank you.

Comment: Please give an example, what output do you expect for 20?

Comment: Those are a lot of primes eh. Lots.  Infinite amount of primes. More primes than atoms in the universe. More primes than all the possible combinations of atoms in the universe. Those are, my friend, a lot of primes.

Comment: You may need to [download some more RAM](http://downloadmoreram.com/).

Comment: This is an active problem for supercomputing, they haven't hit a ceiling yet so there's still time for you to work in...

Comment: You should definitively download more RAM if you want to count all those primes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always have to provide an upper limit. If you wanted prime numbers "greater than or equal to the given value," they would go to infinity.

I would suggest starting with "less than or equal to," provide the function with an upper limit, and then use a conditional to filter out those that are too small.

Comment: I have a matrix, from which i have to do following two tasks: 1) To find prime no from that matrix. 2) Replace only prime numbers which are greater than 7. how I will do it?

Comment: @harshadsinkar There are several techniques to know if a number is prime that do not need to have a list of prime numbers!